# Is it possible to automatically switch to a second printer once the first runs out of paper?

Tags: printing

My question is as follows: I'm configuring a POS system thats will be running on Ubuntu 14.04 and it has 2 identical thermal printers. The printers are already installed and working (somewhat) fine, but i need if possible to make the system automatically switch from one printer to the other once the paper roll runs out on the first printer.
Is it possible? If so, how?